# Pulling a dynamic key value from a JSON array search result query

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I use Wikipedia API to search for Wiki articles. When I click the submit button I get an Array in JSON as a result :

```
0 {ns: 0, title: "Help", size: 3677, wordcount: 433, snippet: "<span class=\"searchmatch\">Help</span> is any form …mmand-line shells that invokes documentations and", …}

1 {ns: 0, title: "Online help", size: 7326, wordcount: 380, snippet: "(HTML), which includes HTML <span class=\"searchmat…earchmatch\">help</span> is also provided via live", …}

2 {ns: 0, title: "Help desk", size: 9491, wordcount: 1296, snippet: "A <span class=\"searchmatch\">help</span> desk is a …ated to a company's or institution's products and", …}

...
```

I need to pull the value of the title and use it inside the HTML in a results list and at the same time put it inside the url so the user can click on a result and go to the corresponding page. (url:http://../[title])

The array is located in data.query.search

Since the results are dynamic I would probably need some kind of a for loop that will iterate through this array no matter how many results there are. I have tried with this for loop but it doesn't work.

```
console.log(data.query.search); //shows array in console
          data.query.search =""; //the location of JSON array
 for (i = 0; i < data.query.search["results"].length; i++) {
  data.query.search["results"][i]["title"];
  console.log("results"); 
}
```

I suspect that I am not targeting the array elements,keys and values properly. I am grateful for any suggestion. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some weird things. First, you are "clearing" `data.query.search` in the second line. Second, in the loop, you don't assign the `title` of each result to any variable and just print "results". Third, you said the array is in `data.query.search`, but you try to access a property `results`. You can try the following:

```js
var data = { query: { search: [
  {ns: 0, title: "Help", size: 3677, wordcount: 433},
  {ns: 0, title: "Online help", size: 7326, wordcount: 380},
  {ns: 0, title: "Help desk", size: 9491, wordcount: 1296}
]}};

for (var i = 0; i < data.query.search.length; i++) {
  var result = data.query.search[i];
  var title = result.title;

  console.log(title);
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks, I have really messed up the code. I have used only the for loop part because data is already "defined" with a function which triggers when getting a JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/oebq0ywj/

```js
var data = { query: { search: [
  {ns: 0, title: "Help", size: 3677, wordcount: 433},
  {ns: 0, title: "Online help", size: 7326, wordcount: 380},
  {ns: 0, title: "Help desk", size: 9491, wordcount: 1296}
]}};

for(var i in data.query.search) {
 console.log(data.query.search[i].title);
}
```

Comment: Instead of pasting a whole code, please consider explaining what it does.

Comment: Sure @Mistalis... Going forward will take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = { query: { search: [
  {ns: 0, title: "Help", size: 3677, wordcount: 433},
  {ns: 0, title: "Online help", size: 7326, wordcount: 380},
  {ns: 0, title: "Help desk", size: 9491, wordcount: 1296}
]}};


var  titleArray = data.query.search.map(function(arrObj) {
  return arrObj.title;
})

  console.log(titleArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Instead of pasting a whole code, explain what it does.